# Grails Domain Update vs Database Trigger Update

Tags: sql-server, grails, grails-orm

I have 2 tables, first one is parent table and second one is child table.

```
Table Employee:
Emp_Id, Name, Age, Salary, Travel_Allowance, Cost_To_Company

Table Allowance:
Id, Emp_Id, Type, Amount
```

Here I need to update Travel_Allowance column of Employee table whenever a row inserted/updated for Travel_Allowance type record in Allowance table.

For this I have written a trigger on Allowance table to update Employee table Travel_Allowance column whenever an insert/update performed on Travel_Allowance type record.

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [trig_updateEmployeeOnAllowanceUpsert]
ON [Allowance]
FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS

UPDATE Employee SET Travel_Allowance = i.amount
FROM Employee e 
INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON e.emp_id = i.emp_id
AND i.type = 'TravelAllowance';
```

In Grails, my code will be as below:

```
class Employee {
    String name
    Integer age
    BigDecimal salary
    BigDecimal travelAllowance
    BigDecimal costToCompany
    static hasMany = [allowances: Allowance]
}

class Allowance {
    Employee employee
    BigDecimal amount

    static belongsTo = [employee: Employee]
}
```

A) Prepares Allowance objects and adds them to Employee object like-

```
def updateAllowances(def employeeId, def allowanceAmount) {
    Employee emp = Employee.get(employeeId)
    Allowance a = new Allowance()
    a.employee = emp
    a.amount = allowanceAmount
    emp.addToAllowances(a)

    // Calculate Cost To Company
    def newCost = 0
    emp.alowances.each { allowance ->
        newCost += allowance.amount
    }
    emp.costToCompany = newCost + emp.salary;
    emp.save(flush:true, failOnError: true)
}
```

Above code is working fine when updating existing Travel_Allowance type record. But while adding new Travel_Allowance type record this is not working as expected.

While adding a new Travel_Allowance type record, trigger is updating Employee table with the new Allowance record amount. Then Grails overriding the same record with previous value in Travel_allowance column.

How to make Grails not to override the value updated from Database trigger?

Comment: Are you sure you want to go down this route? Grails (actually GORM/Hibernate) has its way of doing things. It does not expect triggers to change things behind it's back. So you'll be fighting against Grails with all sorts of edge cases by trying to synchronize a value. If you must, it can be done, but for the sake of not pulling your hair out, consider keeping the one true source for the value, and using a query to retrieve it when you need it.

Comment: I agree with Emmanuel, is this scenario is better to use what Hibernate provides instead of using triggers. Also, with triggers you're strongly depending on your database, what if you need to support another database in the future? Will rewrite all triggers to the second db?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa My client requirement is using the Trigger for this use case. I did this using Grails which is working fine. But my client asking for trigger instead of having this in Grails.
Is there a solution to fix this issue?

Comment: Hmm, I got an idea. Hold on...

Answer (score 2):

OK, I *think* you can use a Grails derived property to solve this. A derived property is basically a SQL calculated field. So what you can do is make `travelAllowance` a derived property which simply returns the `Travel_Allowance` SQL column:

```
class Employee {
    String name
    Integer age
    BigDecimal salary
    BigDecimal travelAllowance
    BigDecimal costToCompany
    static hasMany = [allowances: Allowance]

    static mapping = {
        travelAllowance formula: 'Travel_Allowance'
    }
}
```

This will tell GORM/Hibernate to make `Employee.travelAllowance` read-only, meaning it will not persist changes to the property. Instead, it will always simply read the value from the table, hence, it won't override the value when you save an `Employee` instance. This means the trigger will be completely responsible for maintaining that value; through the `Allowance` instance.

You probably already have a mapping for the `travelAllowance` since your table schema doesn't match what Grails expects. Maybe something like this?

```
static mapping = {
    travelAllowance column: "Travel_Allowance"
}
```

If so, just change it like in my example.

### Warning

A side-effect of changing `travelAllowance` to a derived property is that Grails will not generate that table column for you when doing a schema create/update. As far as Grails is concerned, that column doesn't exist. Something to keep in mind.